# Has or have in this sentence?

Tags: verb-agreement

The two leadership styles combined have a demonstrable effect on team effectiveness

or

The two leadership styles combined has a demonstrable effect on team effectiveness

Answer (score 1):

Replacing "the two leadership styles" with the plural "they", you could rephrase the sentence as:

"Combined, *they* have a demonstrable effect on team effectiveness."

The word "has" is used with a third singular person (he/she/it or a noun), and "have" is used in all other cases. Since "the two leadership styles" is not singular, the entire phrase must be followed by "have".

A complete list of the conjugation for the verb is [here](http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-have.html).

Answer (score -1):

I think the answer would be the first one

> The two leadership styles combined have a demonstrable effect on team effectiveness

#### Explanation:-

The sentence above is about style, the subject `leadarship styles`.
Anyone can easily get confused with the words following the subjects ie. `combined` or any of these `merged, mixed, together`. Even-if it still conveys the idea that some multiple subjects are combined into one, the verb agreement should always be plural.

That's what I think and I will be glad if anyone makes me correct.